# Limiting CPU hyperthreads that cgroup tasks are allowed to access?

Tags: cgroups

Just a quick question about using [CPUSET](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpuset) to limit the CPUs a cgroup can access when using a multi-core CPU with hyper-threading. The documentation linked above says:

> cpuset.cpus (mandatory)
>       specifies the CPUs that tasks in this cgroup are permitted to access. This is a comma-separated list, with dashes ("-") to represent
>   ranges. For example,
>
> ```
> 0-2,16
>
> represents CPUs 0, 1, 2, and 16.
> ```

*Do the CPU numbers refer to the CPU cores or the hyperthreads?*

I'd like to get fine-grained control at the hyperthread level, but wasn't sure what the documentation is referring to by "CPUs".